# Spotlight overlay stopped working on Catalina

Tags: finder, catalina, spotlight

The spotlight overlay that is available via cmd+space suddenly stopped working. First I thought it was maybe a conflicting keyboard shortcut. But clicking on the little search icon in the top right bar also doesn't work. Using Spotlight in a Finder window on the other hand is working.

Restarting my mac solves the issue, but only for a moment. Then it stops working again. I don't see any crashed processes in Activity Monitor.

This is happening on macOS **Catalina 10.15.2**

Has anyone seen this before? Not really sure what to do about it.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind. I had an external screen connected and am using spaces. The overlay did just open in a not active space not visible to me...

Comment: This is my problem as well. What was the solution?

Comment: Update: I solved it by using a keyboard shortcut to maximize Spotlight when I knew it was (invisibly) open, then using the keyboard to drag the Spotlight window to a new location.